# Spring REST Docs: Non-English character string not working in custom snippet table column

Tags: asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I've defined a custom snippet template for response-fields.adoc to include an additional column where i used Chinese characters for the name of that new column. The problem is that the generated snippet doesn't show the column name in the correct Chinese characters, although the data in the column are showing correctly in Chinese.

My response-fields.snippet file is encoded in UTF-8.

**This is my custom snippet template:**

```
|===
|Field|Type|Description|中文描述

{{#fields}}
|{{path}}
|{{type}}
|{{description}}
|{{description_zh_tw}}

{{/fields}}
|===
```

**Expected generated snippet:**

```
|===
|Field|Type|Description|中文描述

|responseStatus
|String
|ID of the team.
|測試

|infected
|String
|ID of the team.
|測試

|fileName
|String
|ID of the team.
|測試

|===
```

**Actual generated snippet:**

```
|===
|Field|Type|Description|銝剜��膩        <==== encoding problem?

|responseStatus
|String
|ID of the team.
|測試

|infected
|String
|ID of the team.
|測試

|fileName
|String
|ID of the team.
|測試

|===
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding of the snippet template from **UTF-8** to **Big5** resolves the issues.